# Selections for graphics drivers are disabled

Tags: drivers, graphics, ati, multiple-monitors

Yesterday I moved to the `proprietary drivers` from the `X.org drivers` using the `Additional Drivers` application, and reverted back to the `X.Org AMD/ATI drivers` on my machine.

I've just booted my machine now after yesterday, and my multi-monitor setup is not working. I can't change the multi-monitor settings in the `Screen Display` section of the system settings.

I checked my graphics drivers and  noticed this:

[image]

It will not let me revert back to my old settings, and I'm not sure why. I want to be able to have the option to choose any of the drivers, and I also want the X.Org drivers to be used.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To revert back to open source **radeon** drivers - open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge fglrx  
sudo reboot
```

If you want to use **AMD Catalyst** drivers again, open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx  
sudo reboot
```